# Query to populate a leaderboard with entry conditions

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have 3 tables:

```
PLAYER        (NAME)
ALL_GOALS     (TYPE, GROUP        , POINTS)
GOALS_REACHED (TYPE, EARNED_POINTS, PLAYER_NAME)
```

I need to write a query which gives me the leaderboard.

A player can enter the leaderboard if and only if he reaches at least one goal with `GROUP='IMPORTANT'`.

For example:

```
 +--------------+
 | PLAYER       |
 +--------------+
 | John         |
 | Bill         |
 | Bob          |
 | Willy        |
 +--------------+

 +-------------------+
 | ALL_GOALS         |
 +-------------------+
 | A, IMPORTANT, 100 |
 | B, IMPORTANT, 200 |
 | C, OTHER, 10      |
 | D, OTHER, 10      |
 +-------------------+

 +--------------+
 | GOALS_REACHED|
 +--------------+
 | A, 100, John |
 | B, 200, Willy|
 | C, 10, Bob   |
 | D, 10, Bob   |
 +--------------+
```

I'd like to see in my leaderboard only John and Willy

Comment: Are the points in the GOALS_REACHED table the same as in the ALL_GOALS table? And if they are, then why do you need to repeat them in the GOALS_REACHED table? That's a poor data model that can only create problems.

Comment: What if John achieved more than one goal (maybe even more than one important goal)? Do you need to show him multiple times? Then - why do you care about points at all? Doesn't a "leaderboard" depend on total points earned, or something like that? There is no mention of it in your question. Please clarify.

Comment: Hi @mathguy, the points in the GOALS_REACHED can be different because the ALL_GOALS can change during its life and my boss doesn't want to trace the changes. Then goal A day 1 can have 100 points and day 100 can have 50 points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? (Sample data in lines #1 - 13; query begins at line #14)

```
SQL> with
  2  all_goals (type, cgroup, points) as
  3    (select 'A', 'IMPORTANT', 100 from dual union all
  4     select 'B', 'IMPORTANT', 200 from dual union all
  5     select 'C', 'OTHER'    ,  10 from dual union all
  6     select 'D', 'OTHER'    ,  10 from dual
  7    ),
  8  goals_reached (type, earned_points, player_name) as
  9    (select 'A', 100, 'John'  from dual union all
 10     select 'B', 200, 'Willy' from dual union all
 11     select 'C',  10, 'Bob'   from dual union all
 12     select 'D',  10, 'Bob'   from dual
 13    )
 14  select r.player_name
 15  from goals_reached r join all_goals g on g.type = r.type
 16  where g.cgroup = 'IMPORTANT'
 17    and g.points > 0;

PLAYE
-----
John
Willy

SQL>
```

Comment: Do we expect that there will be "important" goals that are awarded 0 points? Also, there seems to be no aggregation in your query. If John has achieved five goals, three of which were important, he will appear three times in the output; probably not the OP's requirement.

Comment: No idea, @mathguy. All I know is what the OP posted, with sample data he posted. Quite a few "ifs" in your comment, and I - unfortunately - don't have answer to any of them. You should ask the OP.

Comment: My point is - didn't you have the same questions? (And if not, why not?) If you did, why not ask the OP first, rather than post an answer based on assumptions that may or may not be correct, and that weren't stated in the answer?

Comment: And, specifically about the "points > 0" condition, that is not based on anything the OP said or showed. No mention in his question, and in his sample data all the "points" are positive already.

Comment: Hi @Littlefoot, thanks a lot I'll try your solution asap

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Littlefoot answer and @mathguy useful comments, I improved the query and create a view based on it. This one looks most like an unordered leaderboard.

```
select gr1.PLAYER_NAME, sum(gr1.EARNED_POINTS)
from GOALS_REACHED gr1
where exists(
  select *
  from GOALS_REACHED gr2
       inner join ALL_GOALS ag
       on gr2.TYPE=ag.TYPE
  where ag.GROUP='IMPORTANT' 
        and gr1.PLAYER_NAME=gr2.PLAYER_NAME
)
group by gr1.PLAYER_NAME
```